# Objective-C: is there a precise definition for an initializer?

Tags: objective-c

I read here ([Is there a convention for naming initializer method in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247960/is-there-a-convention-for-naming-initializer-method-in-objective-c/2248289#2248289)) that "according to Apple, initializer methods should always begin with the word 'init'".

**But, what is an initializer?**

I know what is the "designated initializer". You could define it recursively: it is the only method calling the designated initializer of `super` ; plus: the designated initializer of NSObject is `init`.

**But, what is an initializer?**

I am asking this question because I hesitate between two names for an instance method of the class `IceCream` :

- `- (id)initIceCreamWithFlavour:`
- `- (id)iceCreamWithFlavour:` ("called on `alloc`")

I feel that relatively to the naming conventions of ARC, both names are OK. (This is my main concern here. Comments are welcome.) Now that I ask the question, the 
solution `(id)iceCreamWithFlavour:` seems better.

But the question still holds: **what is an initializer?**

I would say: an initializer is a method you "call on `alloc`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "initializer" is a "method in the init family" or "init method", for short.

"Method families" are defined in the ["Clang/ARC documentation"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html):

> A selector is in a certain selector family if, ignoring any leading
>   underscores, the first component of the selector either consists
>   entirely of the name of the method family or it begins with that name
>   followed by a character other than a lowercase letter.

In addition:

> `init` methods must be instance methods and must return an Objective-C pointer type.

So `init` and `initWithFlavour:` are "init methods", but `iceCreamWithFlavour:` or `initialFoo` are not.

A method can also explicitly marked as an init method:

```
-(id)myUnusualInitMethod __attribute__((objc_method_family( init )));
```

The Clang/ARC documentation also states what makes "init methods" special:

> - Methods in the `init` family implicitly consume their `self` parameter and return a retained object. Neither of these properties
>     can be altered through attributes.
> - A call to an `init` method with a receiver that is either `self` (possibly parenthesized or casted) or `super` is called a delegate
>     init call. It is an error for a delegate init call to be made except
>     from an `init` method, and excluding blocks within such methods.
> - As an exception to the usual rule, the variable `self` is mutable in an `init` method and has the usual semantics for a `__strong`
>     variable. ...

So in short

- "Init methods" are the ones that are allowed allowed to call `self = [super init];`
  or `self = [self initWithSomeThing:]`,
- to be an "init method", the method name has to start with "init".

On the other hand, the `+[NSObject alloc]` documentation states:

> You must use an init... method to complete the initialization process.

and the `-[NSObject init]` documentation states:

> In a custom implementation of this method, you must invoke super’s
>   designated initializer then initialize and return the new object.

which together means that `alloc` **must be followed** by a method from the "init family".

Comment: So, if my method don't use `self = [super init...]` there is no necessity to call it with `init` as a prefix. Since I call it above `alloc`, the object returned will be retained?

Comment: Great answer by the way. You deserve your 73k.

Comment: @Colas: Thanks. - An initializer *has to* call `self = [super init...]` ultimately, and therefore the initializer needs the "init" prefix. I have updated the answer to make that clear.

Comment: yes it's true. Every method returning an object has to call ultimately `init...` but not necessarily on `super`. I just came to know about the naming conventions about ARC and I am afraid of having done mistakes. I think I cannot have ghosts but only leaks. Do you have a good link of this topic? Thanks!

Comment: @Colas: What I meant is: `initA` can call `self = [self initB]`, and that might call `self = [self initC]`, but the last element in the chain, the designated initializer, calls `self = [super init...]`. So *ultimately*, every initializer calls `[super init]`, either directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 6):

I would use `- (id)initWithFlavour:`.

So you would have:

```
IceCream *iceCream = [[IceCream alloc] initWithFlavour:Chocolate];
```

which tell you everything you need to know at a glance about the class and the initialisation parameter purpose. Restating ice cream in the method name is superfluous.

As for what the `init` method is, it's just the initialiser for the class. It's purpose is to create a configured new instance. To setup the default values (with, as in this case, some overrides or specific settings).

From your other method naming attempt, you could have:

```
+ (id)iceCreamWithFlavour:
```

Note the plus instead of minus, so this is a class method. This would be a suitable name for a convenience method which calls `alloc] initWithFlavour:` and returns the new instance.

Incidentally, if we add more parameters, don't restate `with`:

```
IceCream *iceCream = [[IceCream alloc] initWithFlavour:Chocolate sprinkles:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C uses a 2 step creation process for objects.
The first step is memory allocation, and the second step is initialisation (which sets the initial state of an object):

```
MYIceCream* iceCream = [[MYIceCream alloc] initWithFlavor:@"Cherry"];
```

You can have multiple `init` methods for your classes, but you should have only one of them that sets the complete state for a new object. This is the designated initialiser (which usually takes the most parameters).
The `MYIceCream` class could have the following designated initialiser:

```
- (id)initWithFlavor:(NSString*)flavorName topping:(NSString*)toppingName
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        _flavorName = flavorName;
        _toppingName = toppingName;
    }
    return self;
}
```

All other initialisers would just call the above method and provide defaults (or `nil`) for some parameters:

```
 - (id)initWithFlavor:(NSString*)flavorName
{
    return [self initWithFlavor:flavorName topping:kMYToppingChoclate];
}
```

You can also define methods, that combine allocation and initialisation. Those are called factory methods. They are defined as class methods (denoted with a `+` sign) and *don't* have an `init` prefix:

```
+ (id)iceCreamWithFlavor:(NSString*)flavorName;
```

The factory method would just call `alloc` and `init` in it's implementation:

```
+ (id)iceCreamWithFlavor:(NSString*)flavorName
{
    return [[MYIceCream alloc] initWithName:flavorName];
}
```

Apple has a good intro to initialisers in the [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ObjectCreation.html) guide and another good read in the [Objective-C Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3).

Answer (score 3):

> I would say: an initializer is a method you "call on alloc"

Thats partly true.

There are 3 types of "direct" initializers as far as i know :

> [init]  initializer (following [X alloc] call)

Initializers starting with "init" always follow an alloc call. I haven't seen any UIKit or Foundation Class being initialized like : <strike>[[NSArray alloc] arrayWithObject:]</strike> <- Does not exist like that.

> Class - initializers

Class initializer create an object from a class scope without having called alloc before.
The implementation of this method, however, would sure call an `[[alloc] init]` to create an object.

Example : `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:]`

Class initializers always start with the corresponding class name.

In your case :

`[IceCream iceCreamWithFlavor:]`

> Initializers creating from existing object.

These are creating an object from an existing one. They 'copy' the existing object and alter some properties.

Example: 
`UIColor *red = [UIColor redColor];`

`UIColor *thinRedColor = [red colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];`

They also start with their corresponding class name like the Class - initializers

If you look through the UIKit and Foundation classes, you will find that these patterns are used in every Class ( & Class - Cluster).

So to answer your question:

The "UIKit / Foundation" - way of naming your initializers would be :

When called after `alloc`:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFlavour:
```

When called on an existing object :

```
- (instancetype)iceCreamWithFlavourAlteredByValue:
```

When called on your Class-Object :

```
+ (instancetype)iceCreamWithFlavour:
```

Answer (score 2):

By convention you should use the - (instancetype)initIceCreamWithFlavour: method, and it should call the super init method (or as @Monolo points out below, it could call another init method such as initWithFlavour:size:).

The second one, you would make a class method + (instancetype)iceCreamWithFlavour: and it should allocate an instance and then call the initIceCreamWithFlavour method.

Assuming the class in this case is probably IceCream, I would actually rename the first one to just - (instancetype)initWithFlavour:

Note the usage of instancetype instead of id.

The class would look something like this:

```
+ (instancetype)iceCreamWithFlavour:(NSString*)flavour
{
    return [[IceCream alloc] initWithFlavour:flavour];
}

- (instancetype)initWithFlavour:(NSString*)flavour
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    // Initialize here
    // do whatever you need to with the flavour parameter

    return self;
}
```

Comment: For completeness, an `init…` method does not _have_ to call `super`, it can call another `init` of the same class - which will then have to call `super`.